# How to get the size for all subdirs in Krusader

Tags: krusader

In Total Commander it was ALT + SHIFT + ENTER. Is the same possible in Krusader?
(I am talking about in-place calculations so please no properties window suggestions).

Comment: only slightly related, hope not too off topic, sorry, in the terminal you would `du -h --max-depth=1`, check it out

Answer (score 2):

It does the same, not like hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> on every dir...
But I hope it helps.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0):

See this Krusader help page: http://www.krusader.org/documentation/calculate.html

The contents at the time of writing:

> Calculate Occupied Space
>
> There are two ways to calculate the occupied space of
>   files/directories.
>
> Pressing the Space on a directory under the cursor instantly
>   calculates the occupied size. Pressing Space a second time will toggle
>   the selection of the directory without affecting the selection status
>   of other files/directories. To calculate how much disk space is
>   occupied by the selected files and directories in the active panel
>   select Edit → Calculate Occupied Space. After a small delay, a dialog
>   box will be displayed with total occupied space and the number of
>   files and directories you selected. The space occupied by every
>   selected directory will be shown as if the user just pressed Space on
>   those directories. If the active panel is browsing an archive, the
>   numbers will apply to the unpacked size of the selected files and
>   directories, not their compressed size. After the calculation the
>   selection state will be toggled and the cursor will move one step
>   downwards. Calculating the occupied space on remote file systems is
>   supported.
>
> Note: Performing this operation on a very large file system (thousands
>   of files) may be time-consuming. You can cancel the calculation
>   process at any time by clicking the Cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> worked.  (Sorry for the old posting, but I got here myself in 2023 and didn't find the answer.)